# How do I reference an instance from a symbol in another class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have a symbol called character1 (with its own class Character1), which has a symbol within it with its own instance name: charTarget1 (the target for items to hit).

In another class called Track1 I am trying to reference the instance charTarget1 in a hitTestObject loop but everytime I try and run the code I keep getting the error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property charTarget1.
```

The loop that I'm trying to run is:

```
private function track1Loop(evt:Event):void{
        if(charTarget1.hitTestObject(game1End)){
            gameWin=true
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyReleased);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an object on the stage or something you have added programmatically?

Comment: Its added programmatically by my Main class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure character1 is public and that the charTarget1 is a public var and both are available to the Track1 class.  You'd have to include the MainClass (don't know what it is named) and the instance of the Character1 class.  This will work below:

```
private function track1Loop(evt:Event):void{
    if(MainClass.character1.charTarget1.hitTestObject(game1End)){
        gameWin=true
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyReleased);
    }
}
```

However, given that you have probably more than a few things you need to keep track of, it might be better to set up some sort of data class that keeps track of all your models and maybe make it a public static class or even a Singleton so you can access them any where in the code without having to pass them into all the classes.